# Problem with nested mapping for Dataset structures

Tags: dataset

Consider the following dataset:

```
data = Dataset[{ <|"a" -> <|"A" -> 1, "B" -> 2|>, "b" -> <|"X" -> 5, "Y" -> 7|>|>,
                 <|"a" -> <|"A" -> 4, "B" -> 2|>, "b" -> <|"X" -> 6, "Y" -> 8|>|>,
                 <|"a" -> <|"A" -> 2, "B" -> 7|>, "b" -> <|"X" -> 3, "Y" -> 1|>|>}]
```

It has nested fields for grouping, so, for example, we'd access what might be called `data[2].b.X` in another language as `data[2, "b", "X"]` (to get the value `6`).

In my application, I'm looking to modify each of the values of a given (terminal) field by combining them in a certain way with the values of another (terminal) field. For example, I might want to adjust all the so-called `data[].a.B`'s by replacing them with `data[].a.B - data[].b.Y`.

My first approach was to use the way Datasets allow you to map at a field name. For example, if I wanted to double all of the `data[].a.B`'s, I could do that with `data = data[{All -> {"a" -> {"B" -> (2*# &)}}}]`, which gives me back the original dataset with that 'column' of `1`, `4`, `2` pictured above having become `2`, `8`, `4`.

But to include the field values under `b`, this has to become a function of each of the list indices; that is, it needs to become `data = data[{All -> somefunction}]`. This function, in turn, involves mapping a function at specific field names of a dataset: each of its arguments is the sub-dataset consisting of a single association (with keys `"a"`, `"b"`). So to implement `data[].a.B - data[].b.Y`, we could try something like

```
data = data[{All -> Function[a, a[{"a" -> {"B" -> (# - a["b", "X"] &)}}] ] }]
```

However, this doesn't work! It seems as though you can't nest dataset queries/actions inside things acting on parts of datasets.

Why doesn't this work, and is there a convenient workaround?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The exhibited expression does not work because the function argument `a` is an association.  Query syntax is only recognized when it appears within the arguments of a `Dataset` or `Query` expression.  We can use `Query` to fix up the function:

```
data[{All -> Function[a, a // Query[{"a" -> {"B" -> (# - a["b", "X"] &)}}]]}]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

As an aside... the following expression violates the spirit of the question but it reads fairly well:

```
data[All, Module[{a = #}, a["a", "B"] -= a["b", "X"]; a] &]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

Comment: Very nice (for consistency's sake) that you can essentially use the `Query` syntax as long as you wrap it in `Query` first! I wasn't aware you could apply `Query` to associations directly. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

I realized while writing this what the problem was, and thought I'd write it up just to share. The problem is this line:

> This function, in turn, involves mapping a function at specific field names of a dataset: each of its arguments is the sub-dataset consisting of a single association (with keys `"a"`, `"b"`).

That's not true! Each argument to `somefunction` is the un-Dataset-ified *association*. It's easy to think "all subparts of Datasets are Datasets", though; after all, querying the dataset to get the first association doesn't return an Association object—it returns a Dataset! That is, `data[1]` has head `Dataset`.

Anyway, to solve it, we have to revert back to using Association tools—in this case, `MapAt`. we want

```
data[{All -> Function[a, MapAt[# - a["b", "X"] &, a, {"a", "B"}]] }]
```

That does the trick. However, I'd be interested if anyone knows how to do this by employing only the Dataset structure and not reverting back to acting on its component pieces—especially the functionality of combining parts of the same dataset for each element in a dataset.

(Would this be worth a feature suggestion if there is clean Dataset-only way to do it, or not?)